# TableLayout for Multiple Screen Sizes?

Tags: android, xml, layout, user-interface, multiscreen

I am building a guitar app.
On the right hand side of the screen will be the fretboard, and on the left will be a few buttons.

I have built the guitar neck with a tablelayout filled with buttons. Nothing special. This is working fairly well. However I would like to support tablets too.

The width of the guitar neck must stay consistent per device, and must always be aligned against the side of the screen. However, because a tablet device is taller, I would like to include MORE notes. Please see the image below.

[image: Layout on Phone vs Tablet]

Can anyone give me any tips on implementing this?
Thanks a bunch

EDIT*

Here is the current basic XML layout. The screen is landscape, with the fretboard at the top. I would think that I would have to take a completely different approach for multi-screen dev.

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TableLayout>
        x6 <TableRow> x5 <Button/> </TableRow>
        (6 TableRows, each with 5x buttons, because that is all that fits on the current display.)
    </TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
       this will hold a set of buttons below the fretboard... 
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put your code what you tried now

Comment: Okay.. so those images are what you want, how about telling us what you got right now so we know where to guide you? Also as @anddevmanu mentioned, let us see the XML file.

Comment: Alright, thanks. To be clear, what I HAVE is the setup for the phone size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alternative resource based on android documentation. it is based on the size and density of the current screen, the system uses any size- and density-specific resource provided in your application. 
For further ado please read this android documentation

[Support multiple Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

As for your question. I would suggest that you create a new folder under res

1. layout-sw600dp
   (for 7 inches tablet)
2. layout-sw600dp (for 10 inches tablet)

Please read more about multiple screen and image resolution..

Cheers.
Androyds

Answer (score 0):

you can try this by giving weight property to the rows of table layout.

hope [this](http://androiddreamers.blogspot.in/2012/09/example-of-table-layout.html) link helps